# Recover partition in / which is umounted

Tags: 10.04, partitioning

I have a partition `/data` which supposed to store data and its format is ext4. Since it not in home folder and I forget to format it as FAT at the beginning, I cannot copy any file into here unless I use root access. Eventually I decide to umount it.

After that, I always get the prompt `/data is not mounted. Press S to skip, or press M to manually recover` at booting screen. It is a bit annoying to me. If I manually recover by mount command, I can see `/data` visible but for just only that time. The next time the message appear again.

Anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks.

BTW, how could I change the partition format from ext4 to FAT? I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Please post up your `/etc/fstab`, it will make things easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `fsck -n /data` (after it is mounted), and note if there are any errors present. If you want to fix them, re-run it without the `-n` flag.

To format it to FAT32, you will have to copy your files from `/data` elsewhere, something like `~/data` is a good idea (`~` is the home directory, make sure there is enough space). Then fire up the `Disk Utility` (located under `System->Administration` menu), select the `/data` partition and format it as FAT32.

Alternatively, if you want to keep `ext4`, and make it user-writeable, you can run `sudo chown USERNAME:users /data -R`.

Comment: As fsck.ext4 man page says, it is not advisable to check a mounted filesystem, even when -n option is used.

Comment: Great thanks. I mount it into /media/data. I can use it as FAT format from now on